# How do I trap a requestexception in an Ajax request in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: ajax, sencha-touch-2

In my Sencha Touch app Ext.device.Connection.isOnline() will return true if the device is connected to wifi but doesn't have an internet connection - so my Ajax calls hang. I'm trying to trap the requestexception event so I can handle the error gracefully, but can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                url:    [my url],
                jsonData:{ },
                params:{
                    op:     'myop'

                },

                method:"POST",
                success:function(response, opts){
                    // all good

                },
                failure:function(response, opts){
                    // failed
                },

                listeners: {
                    requestexception: function(connection, response, options,  eOpts) {


                        switch(response.status) {
                            case 0 :
                              Ext.Msg.alert('Error Loading', 'No Internet connection.');
                              break;

                            default :
                              Ext.Msg.alert('Whoops!', 'An unexpected error has occurred.');
                          }

                    }
                }


            });
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonStore',`

`extend: 'Ext.data.Store',`

```
config: {
    storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
},

constructor: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.getProxy().on([{
        fn: 'onAjaxproxyException',
        event: 'exception',
        scope: me
    }]);
},

onAjaxproxyException: function(server, response, operation, options) {
             //Your code here
}
```

`});`